# Intellij uexpected quote behaivor

Tags: intellij-idea

When I start typing a quoted text I hit **"** and begin typing my text. At the end I hit again **"** to close the quote.

However, what happens next is completely wrong and annoying.
[image]
In the picture above the ending quote is **underlined**. In order to fix it I have to type any character to make it go away. The typed character is not printed and the underline form **"** goes away.

When I don't do this and now put the cursor to another position in the code while the **"** is still underlined and start typing again the first character at the new cursor position is the **"**. The **"** where it was before is removed or moved to the new cursor position.

[image: Animated Gif showing quote problem]

How can have a normal quote behavior?
I couldn't find any other quote setting in the config.

Btw. The **Insert pair quotes** setting is disabled

Intellij 13.1.5, MacOS 10.9

Comment: I just tried this on 13.1.5 and the latest EAP of 14 (Windows version) and it doesn't happen to me. Maybe it's a bug that manifests itself only under certain conditions? Have you tried reporting it on youtrack.jetbrains.com?

Comment: no I thought it is an option I selected. are you on macos as well?

Comment: I am not. I'm using Windows/Linux. I just tried it on Linux version of 13.1.5 and was unable to reproduce it (same with Windows). If you have time try this: Delete your ~/.IntelliJIdea13 folder (back it up first of course), which should reset IDE settings, open IntelliJ, create empty project and see if you still have the problem (just to rule out some misconfiguration of IDE/Project). Afterwards restore your backed up ~/.IntelliJIdea13 folder. If the problem still persists it's probably a bug.

Comment: Congratulations, you found another "this only happens on macOS on tuesdays" bug ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Normally I use a US layout to hack and the German layout for anything else.

I always wondered what is the actual difference between the **US Layout** and **US International (PC)** layout. Turns out, that the described problem in my question is one of those differences.

After switching from **US International (PC)** to **US Layout,** the problem is gone.

Comment: I'm going to assume that's used to write ä,ü,ö on the international keyboard. Maybe ß and other characters.

Comment: I don't know how one could do it. But with the normal US Layout one can also write äöü. You just hold aou for about 1-2 second. then there is pop-up just like on iOS.  Also sometimes your OS freezes when you do it but thats another story :)

Comment: OMG! You saved my life. I already was so depressed about this behavior!